# is there a way to enable support of :focus on form elements in IE also?

Tags: css, cross-browser

is there a valid way to enable support of `:focus` on form elements in IE also?

Comment: Why it's jitendra - what's up with the nick change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without scripting. `$(el).focus(function(){})` and don't forget `blur`

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/